# This/he is studying

Tags: meaning, present-participles, dictionaries

1. This is studying.
2. He is studying.

With #1, is this thing *studying*, or it is  an explanation or definition about studying?

Comment: #1 is ambiguous. *This* can be the actor of the action *driving*, just as *he* is the actor in #2.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

"Studying" is used as a noun in the first sentence. In the second sentence, "studying" is used as a verb.

Here's a simple analogy. Imagine someone driving a car. Note the difference here:

> This is driving.

You're referring to the action of driving the car. You don't care who's doing it. You're talking about the whole process of driving a car. It's basically an answer to the question "What is this?".

> He is driving.

You're referring to the person doing the action and because he's the subject who is doing something, we use "driving" as a verb. It's the answer to the question "What is he doing?".

Comment: Thank you. Then since this form is a noun too, when would you say 1. This is a study rather than this is studying, or 2. This is a walk vs. this is walking, and so on?

Comment: @JoeKim You're giving a bad example again. Just remember that when the -ing form is used as a noun, it describes the process. That's it. A noun that matches the infinitive is something entirely different, so don't think about it. "study" as a noun doesn't always match the meaning of the verb. Try not to get bogged down in these things.

Comment: This answer does not take into account that Sentence 1 is ambiguous, because *this* can be the actor of the action *driving*, just as *he* is the actor in #2.